# Why $x \otimes y - y \otimes x = (x - y) \otimes (y-x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I was reading a certain proof and the author used this piece of information  $x \otimes y - y \otimes x = (x - y) \otimes (y-x).$

My question is why  $x \otimes y - y \otimes x = (x-y) \otimes (y-x)$ is correct?

Could anyone explain this to me please?

**EDIT:**

Here is the question I want to answer :

Let $k$ be a field and $B = k[x,y].$ Define $R-$modules $J = (x,y), N = J/J^2$ and $M = J \otimes_B J.$

Define $m \in M$ by $m = x \otimes y - y \otimes x.$ Show that $m \neq 0$ and $m \in tM.$

I got a hint to show that the image of $m$ in $N \otimes_B N$ is not zero. Then find a nonzero element of $\operatorname{ann}(m).$

Here is a trial I found online:

Since there is a natural projection map $J \rightarrow J/J^2,$ then there is also a natural projection $M \rightarrow N \otimes_B N$ (is that correct?) which is the coordinate wise projection map. Take $m \in M,$ where $m = x \otimes y - y \otimes x = (x-y) \otimes (y-x).$ Since both $(x-y)$ and $(y-x)$ lie in $J$ but not in $J^2,$ they project to $(x - y) \otimes (y - x)$ which are both linear and non-zero. So $m$ must have been non zero.

Second, since $xy \in k[x,y]$ then $xym = xy(x \otimes y) - xy(y \otimes x) = xy \otimes xy - xy \otimes xy$ (using the properties of tensor product and the commutativity of $k$) hence $xym = 0,$ so $m$ is indeed a torsion element and hence $m \in tM.$

**My question on the first paragraph is:**

Why  $x \otimes y - y \otimes x = (x-y) \otimes (y-x)$? If it is wrong, how can I correct the solution?

Comment: This isn't correct, unless you're using wedge (rather than tensor) products. Just expand the right hand side and you'll see some extra terms that aren't accounted for in the left.

Comment: This is not correct, the terms  $-x\otimes x$ and $-y\otimes y$ still remain in general. Which is the situation exactly?!

Comment: Ok let me edit my question with the whole details so that you can see the context and help me in correcting that mistake or understand its justification if it is correct @EthanDlugie

Comment: @dan_fulea Ok let me edit my question with the whole details so that you can see the context and help me in correcting that mistake or understand its justification if it is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not correct that $x \otimes y - y \otimes x = (x-y) \otimes (y-x)$ in this case.  Indeed, note that $N$ is just a 2-dimensional vector space over $B/J\cong k$, with $\{x,y\}$ as a basis.  So, $N\otimes_B N=N\otimes_{B/J} N$ is just a tensor product of vector spaces and so it is 4-dimensional with $\{x\otimes x,x\otimes y,y\otimes x,y\otimes y\}$ as a basis.  This shows that $x \otimes y - y \otimes x \neq (x-y) \otimes (y-x)$, but it also just directly shows that $x\otimes y-y\otimes x$ is nonzero.

Comment: it is not clear to me why it directly shows that $x \otimes y - y \otimes x$ is not zero ..... could you please clarify this to me?

Comment: $x\otimes y$ and $y\otimes x$ are two of the basis elements...

Comment: Ohhh .. I see :)

Comment: But is not the tensor product commutative? we proved this before. Why in our case here it is not commutative?

Comment: "Tensor product is commutative" in the sense that there is a natural isomorphism $M\otimes_A N\cong N\otimes_A M$ if $M$ and $N$ are modules over a commutative ring $A$.  That's very different from asking whether the tensor operation on *elements* is commutative, i.e. whether $x\otimes y=y\otimes x$ in $M\otimes_A M$ if $x,y\in M$.

Comment: are not $x,y$ here should be equivalence classes as they are elements of $N$?

Comment: Is my question too  stupid that it does not worth answering? ..... I mean in the 4 dimensional basis of $N \otimes N$

Comment: Sorry, I missed your question before.  Yes, when I write $x$ and $y$ I mean the images of $x$ and $y$ in the quotient $N$.